# PHP IF, ELSE SHOW HELP?

Tags: php

Coming across a massive pain, is they a way I can for example say if has youtubeurl else show vimeourl?
Here is my coding

```
<?php $youtube_vimeo_player = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_youtube_vimeo_player',TRUE); ?>
<?php $info = $video->info("'".$youtube_vimeo_player['youtubeurl']."'"); ?>
<div class="content">
    <div>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo $info['title']; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $info['thumb_large']; ?><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $info['title']; ?><?php echo $info['title']; ?>"  class="thumb"/>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $info = $video->info("'".$youtube_vimeo_player['vimeourl']."'"); ?>
<div class="content">
    <div>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo $info['title']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $info['thumb_large']; ?><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $info['title']; ?><?php echo $info['title']; ?>"  class="thumb"/>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be more then great : )

Comment: that code looks very unreadable, and i see **no** if's or else's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
if ($youtube_video_url) {
    //YouTube Stuff
}
else {
    //Veoh stuff
}
```

??

Answer (score 0):

If your asking how do an if statement inline style then this is how.

```
<? if (something == true) { ?>
<div>something</div>
<? } else { ?>
<div>something else</div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Im trying to make it show       If                               $youtube_vimeo_player['youtubeurl'] else      $youtube_vimeo_player['vimeourl'] end if

Comment: I don't know these variables and functions you are using.  I'm giving you a basic example.  you might be able to do if(isset($youtube_vimeo_player['youtubeurl'])) or if($youtube_vimeo_player['youtubeurl'] == null).  But I can't say for sure.  This should be fairly simple to debug.  If you need help debugging go here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/   Most importantly you need to know how to debug a program or you won't ever get anywhere.  If your going to get your if statement working correctly, you need to at least know what these variables have in them.

Comment: Got it working : ) Just a small coding mistake that I over looked : )